# why tests fails when testing python-glanceclients?

Tags: cloud, openstack

i am using python 2.6.6, why run_tests tried to find python 2.7?

```
(os)mirror0@lab:~/tmp/python-glanceclient$ ./run_tests.sh
GLOB sdist-make: /home/mirror0/tmp/python-glanceclient/setup.py
py27 create: /home/mirror0/tmp/python-glanceclient/.tox/py27
ERROR: InterpreterNotFound: python2.7
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   py27: InterpreterNotFound: python2.7
(os)mirror0@lab:~/tmp/python-glanceclient$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install python 2.7 for these tests to pass.